# mysql combining two tables to produce the following output

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

hello i had ask the same question before but i want another way. we can use locate and max function to solve the question. but my teacher told me to do like this

1. my code is like this when '0' then '1' else '0'

   ```
        select u.id, u.name, 
        case f.finger when '0' then '1' else '0' end as '0',
        case f.finger when '1' then '1' else '0' end as '1',
        case f.finger when '2' then '1' else '0' end as '2',
        case f.finger when '3' then '1' else '0' end as '3',
        case f.finger when '4' then '1' else '0' end as '4',
        case f.finger when '5' then '1' else '0' end as '5'

        from users u left join user_fingerprints f
        on u.id= f.user_id
   ```

   the code above will resulted in 8 rows.
2. then i need to combine the rows so that the rows with the same id combine to produce this
3. from that result then use case function. when the value is 1 then y. when value is zero then n.

can someone give me the answer without the use of max function? thanks 
 the table and result
[image]

Comment: We are not supposed to help with homework. The whole point is that you should do your homework not us http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework

Comment: Your question is very confusing.

First of all, why do you have so many cases. If you are setting 1 when f.finger is 0 - 5, why not use a range?

Secondly, look at the GROUP BY function.

Comment: What if using `sum`?

Comment: @AliIshaq: The point of the cases appears to be to turn `f.finger` into 6 separate flag fields, one for each possible value. Seems an odd thing to do, but i've seen weirder.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `SUM()` and another `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT t.id,t.name,
       CASE WHEN t.`0` > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' as `0`
       CASE WHEN t.`1` > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' as `1`
       ....
FROM (
    SELECT u.id,u.name, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN f.finger = '0' then '1' else '0' end) as `0`,
           SUM(CASE WHEN f.finger = '1' then '1' else '0' end) as `1`,
           ....
    from users u left join user_fingerprints f
     on u.id= f.user_id
    GROUP BY u.id,u.name) t
```